# BASH: Use a String as file output

Tags: bash, unix

In a bash script I need to compare the first char of two Strings.

To do this, I use the `head` operator like this:

```
var1="foo"
var2="doo"
headVar1=$(head -c1 $var1)
headVar2=$(head -c1 $var2)

if [ $headVar1 == $headVar2 ]
  then
    #miau
fi
```

But the console says "head: cant open foo for reading: Doesnt exist the file or directorie"
And the same with doo

Some help?

Thanks.

Comment: You have so many syntax errors. To get the first char use `${var1:0:1}`

Comment: In addition to all that's said in the answers, `==` isn't supported in POSIX `[`. Bash will support it as an extension, but better to use the compliant string comparison operator `=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`head` interpreted `foo` as a filename. See `man head` on what options are available for the command.

To store command output in a variable, use command substitution:

```
headVar1=$(printf %s "$var1" | head -c1)
```

which could be shortened using a "here string":

```
headVar1=$(head -c1 <<< "$var1")
```

But parameter expansion is much faster in this case, as it doesn't spawn a subshell:

```
headVar1=${var1:0:1}
```

Comment: The first form isn't quite right in all cases. `printf '%s\n' "$var1"` will more reliably emit the content faithfully and correctly than `echo "$var1"` will.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Can you give an example?

Comment: Sure: `var1=-n` (in many versions; the POSIX spec makes this behavior implementation-defined). And if you're following the POSIX spec for `echo`, then any string with a literal backslash likewise results in implementation-defined output.

Answer (score 1):

Your code must be,

```
var1="foo"
var2="doo"
headVar1=$(head -c1 <<<"$var1")
headVar2=$(head -c1 <<<"$var2")
if [[ "$headVar1" == "$headVar2" ]]
  then
    echo "It's same"
else
    echo "Not same"
fi
```

- remove the space which exists next to equal sign (*variable assignment part*).
- Use `<<<` to fed input from a variable to the corresponding function.
- Variable names must be preceded by the dollar `$` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

A circuitous, but POSIX-compatible, solution:

```
var1="foo"
var2="doo"
headVar1=${var1%${var1#?}}
headVar2=${var2%${var2#?}}

if [ "$headVar1" = "$headVar2" ]
then
    #miau
fi
```

`${var1#?}` expands to the value of `var1` minus its first character. That is used as the *suffix* to remove with `${var1%...}`, leaving in the end just the first character of `var1`.